# Custom initialization with segue

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I recently began working with UIStoryboards and was hoping someone could help me solve a problem with the way the segue handles initialization.  Basically this is the way I was used to initializing controllers by using a custom initializer.

```
let myController = MyController(dependency: myDependency)
navigationController?.pushViewController(myController, animated: true)
```

But with the segue, I have to set the property in prepareForSegue and have no opportunity to set dependencies in a safe way.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if let identifier = segue.identifier {
          if identifier == "ShowMyController" {
               let myController = segue.destinationViewController as! MyController
               myController.dependency = myDependency
          }
     }
}
```

I think the way prepareForSegue handles this is nasty.  I see some possible issues with the prepareForSegue approach that custom initialization avoids.

1. If I add a dependency to MyController I will get no help from the compiler that I have a new dependency I need to handle.
2. When handing this code to another developer it is harder for them to reason about what dependencies should be set on MyController in order to use it safely.
3. In Swift I have to unwrap and cast the segue in order to set the dependencies.

Any ideas would be helpful!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea of segue is creating and presenting the `UIViewController` without any code. For the developer, the points that you gain by getting the app flow is much more that the initialisation issue (but still, it could be nice to have them both). 
I think that if you will made some DataSource protocols with required functions, it will be hard to miss those points.
If someone have a better idea it will be nice to learn...

Comment: Yeah I understand pushing as much of the logic to the storyboard as possible.  DataSource protocols are a nice idea, I will try that out.